# Using active directory for authentication of both site and app

Tags: ios, authentication, active-directory, moodle, adfs

We have a provider, who developed an **iOS app** for us, so the students can log-in with their **Active Directory** accounts in it. Are the following scenarios possible:

1. Student goes to **link** in the app and browser opens **within** the app and the user is logged in **automatically** in the site from the link (school page with profiles with grades for each student on it)
2. Student goes to **link** in the app and browser opens **outside** the app (in **Safari**), but the user is also **automatically** logged in into his profile.

Is it possible one of the both, or both authentication methods? We are using **Michrosoft ADFS** and **iOS** on iPads, the site is **Moodle**-based.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your architecture, your app's back-end and the type of token that your IDP is providing, but in theory it is possible. This has been possible since Moodle v 1.4.

**Is it possible to have it work as a sub-browser from within the app?** Yes, this would be possible by constructing a webView in Xcode and passing the necessary variables to trigger user authentication before loading content.

**Is it possible to have it work via Safari but launched from within the app?** Also yes, but it depends on the token being passed.

You should consider sing an SSO interface.

You also mention that you use MS Active Directory so if your app is running a .Net backend, you may be able to use Azure. See [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-adal-sso-authentication/).

If you're going all-out and you're constructing your own procedure, consider CAS and Shibboleth SSO as those seem to work most 'natively' with Moodle. LDAP is also fine but will involve some teeth-pulling.